# Preventing duplicate elements in foreign key column

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Using Hibernate 3.1 and have two mapping files m_devotee and m_member with classes M_devotee and M_member. I want to avoid duplicate entries from m_devotee column devotee_id which is referenced as devotee_id foreign key in m_member table.

I'm new to Hibernate and want to know if I'm missing some tags in the mappings.

Here are my files, https://gist.github.com/2e2560e7a04a769848a4

For now, I tried to prevent duplicates by adding code in my dao file. It gives me a ClassCastException. It should also rollback the transaction and return false to the servlet so it does not forward it to other jsp file.

```
Query qr1=session.createQuery("select m.devotee_id from M_member m");  
List<M_member> l1=qr1.list();  
for(M_member mi:l1)  
{  
 if(!(l1.contains(member.getDevotee_id())))  
 {  
  member.setDevotee_id(member.getDevotee_id());  
 //System.out.println("print devotee id"+member.getDevotee_id());  
 }  
}
```

M_devotee object cannot be cast to M_member as seen here.

I'm lost and any help is thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: Mark your foreign key in your mapping with unique, or use a natural-id or composite-id if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear, and it seems to me that you missed the part of the manual talking about associations (and the part of the Java manual talking about naming conventions as well).

But what's sure is that if you query the field devotee_id:

```
select m.devotee_id from M_member m
```

What you'll get as result will be a list of devotee IDs. Not a list of M_member. So, assuming devotee_id is a field of type Long, what you'll get will be a `List<Long>`. Not a `List<M_member>`.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your association between M_member and M_devotee as a bidirectional many-to-one association mapped as a java Set. This way, there is not need for duplicate checks, since the Set interface guarantees that a value is added only once to a collection.

```
<class name="Parent">
    <id name="id" column="parent_id"/>
    ....
    <set name="children" inverse="true">
        <key column="parent_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="Child"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Child">
    <id name="id" column="child_id"/>
    ....
    <many-to-one name="parent" 
        class="Parent" 
        column="parent_id"
        not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

See the Hibernate docs 7.3.2. Bidirectional associations
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional